# What does "XHR Load" mean in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I monitored the performance of our JavaScript application using Chrome's Developer Tools.

The output looks like this:

[image: Output produced]

I don't really understand what "XHR Load" exactly means. According to [Google reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/performance-reference), "XHR Load" is an event. So, what exactly does it mean that the XHR Load took 3014ms (in total)? Does it mean that the execution of the function triggered by this event took 3014ms?

Comment: "XHR" is just a technical name for what people call an "Ajax request". This shows the loading time of the request, that took 3014ms

Comment: Are you sure? I fire only one ajax request. Why should this result in several "XHR Load" entries in the performance table? And "XHR Load" is the ajax request, I still don't know what exactly took 3014ms: the execution of the ajax request, parsing the string into a json object, executing the "success" function, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Check there 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/performance-reference

```
XHR Load =>  An XMLHTTPRequest finished loading.
```

Answer (score -4):

XHR is referred to "XmlHttpRequest" and it allows to make HTTP request in Javascript. Nowadays, there is another method called "fetch" that somewhat deprecates XmlHttpRequest.